# Swift: Determining if a given bundle is an Application?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, bundle, macos-sierra

In Swift 3, if I have, say...

```
import Foundation
let aRandomBundle = Bundle(path:"/A/ValidPath/To/A/Bundle")
```

Is there a convenient way to determine whether aRandomBundle is an application, or a framework, or some other kind of bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing this, which works pretty nicely.

```
extension Bundle {
    func getType (outError: inout OSStatus) -> String? {
        if let info = self.infoDictionary {
        if let type = info["CFBundlePackageType"] {
            return String(describing: type)
        }
        else { outError = kLSNotAnApplicationErr; return nil }
        }
        else { outError = -10810; return nil }
    }
}
```